# PHP continue inside function

Tags: php, function, continue

This is likely very trivial but I haven't been able to figure it out.

This works:

```
function MyFunction(){

//Do stuff

}


foreach($x as $y){

MyFunction();

if($foo === 'bar'){continue;}

//Do stuff

echo $output . '<br>';

}
```

But this doesn't:

```
function MyFunction(){

//Do stuff

if($foo === 'bar'){continue;}

}


foreach($x as $y){

MyFunction();

//Do stuff

echo $output . '<br>';

}
```

That yields only 1 $output and then:

```
Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't break/continue a loop outside a function, from within a function. However, you can break/continue your loop based on the return value of your function:

```
function myFunction(){   
    //Do stuff
    return $foo === 'bar';
}


foreach($x as $y) {
    if(myFunction()) {
        continue;
    }

    //Do stuff

    echo $output . '<br>';    
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) statement is valid inside looping structures only.

Comment: Yes this is correct, I would use `return;` if you want to stop executing a function.

Answer (score 1):

`continue` can only skip iterations inside of a looping structure.

Inside of your function, the context of it being ran inside a loop is lost.

Answer (score 0):

The function is compiled separately and could be called from anywhere. Thus, the use of `continue` makes no sense here as the context is not in that of a loop. If you wish to delegate work to a function here, you should design the function to return some indication of whether to `continue` or not, such as a `TRUE` or `FALSE` return value.