# Is there any possibility to break a loop while calling a function?

Tags: php, loops

Let's say I have a simple code:

```
while(1) {
  myend();
}

function myend() {
  echo rand(0,10);
  echo "<br>";
  if(rand(0,10) < 3) break;
}
```

This will not work with error code 'Fatal error:  Cannot break/continue 1 level on line'.

So is there any possibility to terminate the loop during a subfunctin execution?

Comment: No, you must instead return a value from the function and break based on its value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183713/php-continue-inside-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't. Not should there be; if your function is called somewhere where you're not in a loop, your code will stop dead. In the example above, your calling code should check the return of the function and then decide whether to stop looping itself. For example:

```
while(1) {
  if (myend())
    break;
}

function myend() {
  echo rand(0,10);
  echo "<br>";
  return rand(0,10) < 3;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the loop condition depend upon the return value of the function:

```
$continue = true;
while( $continue) {
    $continue = myend();
}
```

Then, change your function to be something like:

```
function myend() {
  echo rand(0,10);
  echo "<br>";
  return (rand(0,10) < 3) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: rather, `do {... } while(fun())`.

Comment: `myend` in my case will be evaluated too.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$cond = true;
while($cond) {
  $cond = myend();
}

function myend() {
  echo rand(0,10);
  echo "<br>";
  if(rand(0,10) < 3) return false;
}
```